# Can't texture paint on model while using alpha

Tags: transparency, texture-painting, layers

[image]

Hello! Please, can anybody help me, I am stuck.

So, here is the model and I wanted to paint over my base color using texture slot with alpha. The problem is I am not able to paint on my model, when I do it nothing happens and I can see only canvas of the mesh. But if I paint over UV's it works and it shows on the model. What am I doing wrong?

Here I've painted over UV's
[image]

Then I switched a viewport
[image]

Comment: could you please pack the images into your file and share the file? only the part you're trying to paint, and upload here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Can you check your mesh normals direction to see if they are inverted? The mesh will show image from UV map but the direction will be wrong, causing the paint to not appear on the outside - zoom 'inside' your mesh, and try to paint there and see if the paint applies.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I was following this tutorial  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dG_BQ5uXxJc&t=137s and from 2:10 all happens. Mesh does not appear after creating a new slot . Even if I start over with a default cube it still the same. Normal are fine. Here is the file  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6738" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6738/)